# Perform mathematical operations to consecutive rows of the matrix

Tags: r

I have a large matrix (1000*11). I want to calculate the column sum between consecutive rows (first row and second row, third row and forth row, so on). For example,

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

I want to convert the above matrix into following.

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]     3    11    19    27
[2,]     7    15    23    31
```

One way to do that is to split the large matrix into sub matrices and do the calculation and merge the results. Is there a better solution than this?

Comment: Now it has been corrected.

Answer (score 4):

We can just subset the rows of the `matrix` by using a recycling logical index and do a `+`

```
mat[c(TRUE, FALSE),]  + mat[c(FALSE, TRUE),]
```

---

Or with `rowsum`

```
rowsum(mat, group = rep(1:2, each = 2))
```

If there are more rows, then create the 'group' programmatically

```
rowsum(mat, group = as.integer(gl(nrow(mat),2, nrow(mat))))
```

---

Or this can be done with `aggregate` as well

```
aggregate(mat, by = list(rep(1:2, each = 2)), FUN = sum)[-1]
```

#### data

```
mat <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4)
```